# How to remove special characters from url?

Tags: ios, swift, string, url

```
let ids = [String: [String]]

ids=%5B%4566abef1c-4462-4g62-bcc5-5ae10547104c%22,%20%1256efcf8c-6977-430d-b3ec-4ae80547101c%22%5D
```

After appended and passing url params, response failing in response structure special symbol added in -> `%5B%%`

```
https://baseUrl/endpoint?ids=4566abef1c-4462-4g62-bcc5-5ae10547104c,1256efcf8c-6977-430d-b3ec-4ae80547101c
```

How to remove %22%5D from url?

Here Code:

```
let parms: [String: [String]]
let urlString = "\(baseUrl)/\(endpoint)"
Connector.requestSwiftyJson(
    url: urlString,
    requestType: .get,
    withParams: parms,
    loader: false
) { json, response, error in
```

Comment: maybe you can use the method replace from string.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to go from your id’s dictionary to url you show ?

Comment: @PtitXav added my code.

Comment: It seems like `ids` are something like: `["FIRST-ID", "SECOND-ID"]` and you are trying to manually remove all `[` and `"` and `]` in this question. Is this what you want?

Comment: What is requestSwiftifyJson ? What is the contents of parms ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Yes.

Comment: So I have answered that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API to remove the percent encoding

```
let string = "ids=%5B%4566abef1c-4462-4g62-bcc5-5ae10547104c%22,%20%1256efcf8c-6977-430d-b3ec-4ae80547101c%22%5D"
let cleanedString = string.removingPercentEncoding
```

However if you need to extract the UUIDs you can do it with Regular Expression

```
func extractUUID(from string : String) -> [String]
{
    let pattern = "[0-9a-f]{10}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    return matches.map { match -> String in
        let range = Range(match.range, in: string)!
        return String(string[range])
    }
}

let uuids = extractUUID(from: "ids=%5B%4566abef1c-4462-4g62-bcc5-5ae10547104c%22,%20%1256efcf8c-6977-430d-b3ec-4ae80547101c%22%5D")
print(uuids)
```

Note: the `g` in the first UUID is an invalid character

Comment: yes, we all know about `removingPercentEncoding` because it's part of my answer. However, using only  `removingPercentEncoding`  does not 
remove, for example, `"` or `]` or `[`, as required by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove unwanted characters by adapting the parameters right before passing it into the parser like:

```
let adaptedParams = params.reduce(into: [String: String]()) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value.joined(separator: ",") }
```

Answer (score 0):

"...How to remove `%22%5D` from url? ". Try this:

```
 let ids = "%5B%4566abef1c-4462-4g62-bcc5-5ae10547104c%22,%20%1256efcf8c-6977-430d-b3ec-4ae80547101c%22%5D"
 let cleanUrl = ids.replacingOccurrences(of: "%22%5D", with: "")
 print("\n---> cleanUrl: \(cleanUrl) \n")
```

You can also remove all percent encoding using this:

```
   if let cleanUrl = ids.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B", with: "") // [
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%5D", with: "")  // ]
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%22", with: "")  // "
    .removingPercentEncoding {  // other encoding
    
    print("\n---> cleanUrl: \(cleanUrl) \n")
}
```